# mysql.event shows wrong last_executed time

Tags: mysql

I've created an event which runs every 1 hour.
The events "last_executed" time shows (actual exec time) - 2.

For instance, "created" shows {date} 12:58:36 and "last_executed" shows {date} 10:58:36.
I've checked the server time and it matches "created".

Is there some sort of internal time keeping, and if so why is it only used for one of the fields and not the other?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information.  How does last_executed get set?  If it's provided by code and the code runs in a different timezone you would see this behavior.

Comment: It gets set by mysql event_scheduler process every time event scheduler executes the event. It's basically a part of metadata associated with mysql event. No external code in the picture. :)

Comment: You're going to have to post the SQL and any stored procedure code